# is it correct to use "behind" and "back" at the same time?

Tags: expressions

I understand if something is done behind you, it is already unknown to you. Your back has no eyes and therefore one cannot see what's done at their back. I am driving towards the use of "behind my back". it sounds like the opposite. for instance, if someone says the pen is "behind the back" of the book, the person may literally mean the pen in front of the book.

Comment: "Behind the back" of someone is a fixed phrase meaning "without that person's knowledge or approval". We do not say "behind the back" of things, just "behind".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  English is very much a context-dependent language. We simply cannot say from a short phrase whether it works or not. We need to know what you are talking about, what yo want to describe. We also need a complete sentence showing how you want to use the phrase. I hope this helps.

Comment: If somebody said "the pen is behind the back of the book" then I would assume that the back of the book was between the pen and the speaker (or perhaps between the pen and me)

Comment: @Michael Harvey - I think you are being a little too prescriptive. I can think of contexts where the phrase "behind the back" of an object is perfectly acceptable. I'll give some of these in an answer. I'm just waiting for the OP to provide some additional information. Meanwhile here are a few examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22behind+the+back%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01VkI-2YAk_EzSbuxz-KE365nDpgw:1606214406932&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyxKH5_prtAhWVEMAKHWN9Bh4QpwUIJQ&biw=1243&bih=607&dpr=1.5

Comment: I would certainly say that there is redundancy in saying "the book is behind the back of the cupboard".

Comment: @Michael Harvey - I agree, but no-one has suggested that. The question is: *"Is it correct to use “behind” and “back” at the same time?"*   - My answer is Yes, but it depends on the context. That is why I've asked the OP to provide more details.  In general, providing context and sample sentences is encouraged on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isn't "behind your back" in front of you?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/isnt-behind-your-back-in-front-of-you)